# How to add multiple columns with purrr?

Tags: r, purrr

I'm looking for a tidy way to perform the following:

```
iris %>% mutate(
petal_width_pct = Petal.Width/Sepal.Width, 
petal_length_pct = Petal.Length/Sepal.Width,
sepal_length_pct = Sepal.Length/Sepal.Width,
sepal_width_pct = Sepal.Width/Sepal.Width)
```

I'd like to add a percentage column for each numeric column, in a way which doesn't require the listing of each variable. I imagine I need a purrr map of some kind, but I haven't figured it out yet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `map` I think you should look at `across`  :

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~./Sepal.Width, .names  ='{col}_pct'))
```

In `dplyr` versions < 1.0.0 you could use `mutate_if` with same effect.

```
iris %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, list(pct = ~./Sepal.Width))
```